# LGT-256M6G SSD enclosure/converter for SATA connection

Tags: laptop, ssd, sata, conversion

I have this SSD that came from my Lenovo Yoga2 Pro notebook but it doesn't seem to be mSATA, which I originally thought it was.

Here's a picture:

[image]

As said in the title, I just want an enclosure that will convert it to SATA so I can connect to my desktop.

Just to clarify, I have purchased a 2.5" mSATA to SATA converter board to try with this and it does NOT fit. So this is not mSATA!

Comment: Looks a lot like a [m2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2) connector, specifically a type B+M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an [M2/NGFF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2) drive - which [googling the model confirmed](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=LGT-256M6G&oq=LGT-256M6G&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=106&ie=UTF-8) . You need a m2 to sata converter for this.

There's 3 sorts of M2 (NGFF is an older name used with prototypes) drives - PCI-e and SATA based and variations within those. SATA drives are slower than PCIe based one, but more cross compatible, which is why its labelled as such.

Comment: Of course I googled it as well, but I've never heard of N2/NGFF and didn't know what that meant.

Comment: The search was more confirmation. I *vaguely* recognised the form factor by sight.